# Difference in md5sums in two object files

Tags: linux, elf

I compile twice the same .c and .h files and get object files with the same size but different md5sums.
Here is the only difference from `objdump -d`:

1) `cpcidskephemerissegment.o:     file format elf64-x86-64`

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_ZN68_GLOBAL__N_sdk_segment_cpcidskephemerissegment.cpp_00000000_B8B9E66611MinFunctionEii>:
```

2) `cpcidskephemerissegment.o:     file format elf64-x86-64`

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_ZN68_GLOBAL__N_sdk_segment_cpcidskephemerissegment.cpp_00000000_8B65537811MinFunctionEii>:
```

What can be the reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reasons can be many:

- Using macros like `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`
- Embedding counters that are incremented for each build (the Linux kernel does this)
- Timestamps (or similarly variable quantities) embedded in the `.comments` ELF section. One example of a compiler that does this is the xlC compiler on AIX.
- Different names as a result of name mangling (e.g. C++)
- Changes in environment variables which are affecting the build process.
- Compiler bug(s) (however unlikely)

To produce bit identical builds, you can use GCC's `-frandom-seed` parameter. There were situations where it could break things before GCC 4.3, but GCC now turns functions defined in anonymous namespaces into static symbols. However, you will always be safe if you compile each file using a different value for `-frandom-seed`, the simplest way being to use
the filename itself as the seed.

Comment: What can help me to detect the problem?

Comment: Since you've found the difference is in a mangled symbol name, all I can say is I'm not sure the name mangling process can be manipulated. Forcing the function declaration in an `extern "C" {}` block may produce identical object files, but it's not really the right solution. Do you absolutely need identical object files?

Comment: really yes, because it causes different sizes of .so and .rpm files and because of that our product cannot be certified :(

Answer (score 2):

> I guess, the compiler didn't know how to name this namespace and used path to the source file plus some random number.

The compiler must guarantee that a symbol in unnamed namespace does not conflict with any other symbol in your program. *By default* this is achieved by taking full filename of the source, and appending a random hash value to it (it's legal to compile the same source twice (e.g. with different macros) and link the two objects into a single program, and the unnamed namespace symbols *must* still be distinct, so using just the source filename without the seed is not enough).

If you know that you are not linking the same source file more than once, and want to have a bit-identical object file on re-compile, the solution is to add `-frandom-seed="abcd"` to your compile line (replace "abcd" with anything you want; it's common to use the filename as the value of random seed). Documentation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-frandom_002dseed-703).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found the answer!

`c++filt` command gave the original name of the function:

`{unnamed namespace}: MinFunction(int, int)`

In the source was:

```
namespace
{
MinFunction(int a, int b) { ... }
}
```

I named the namespace and got stable checksum of object file!
As I guess, the compiler didn't know how to name this namespace and used path to the source file plus some random number.

Comment: "I've found the answer" -- no, you *didn't*. You've found a workaround. I'll give the real answer shortly.